# Evince "Open Containing Folder" shows "Could not open the containing folder" (Permission denied)

Tags: permissions, pdf, evince

When I open a pdf file using `evince` and then choose `File` > `Open Containing Folder`, then an error message gets shown, stating:

`Could not open the containing folder`

`Failed to execute child process "caja" (Permission denied)`

I am using Ubuntu 16.04LTS 64bit with the Mate desktop.

What can I do to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**AppArmor** is restricting the permissions of `evince`.

Firstly, add the following line to the file `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.evince`:

```
  /usr/bin/caja Cx -> sanitized_helper,     # Mate
```

and save it.

Then restart the **AppArmor** service as follows:

```
sudo service apparmor restart
```

This will resolve the issue.

---

For other file managers one of the following example configurations can be applied:

```
  /usr/bin/nautilus Cx -> sanitized_helper, # Gnome
  /usr/bin/pcmanfm Cx -> sanitized_helper,  # LXDE
  /usr/bin/krusader Cx -> sanitized_helper, # KDE
  /usr/bin/thunar Cx -> sanitized_helper,   # XFCE
```

Multiple lines, as seen above, are allowed as well.

Comment: This would be technically correct answer to avoid the permission problem. However, `/usr/bin/caja` will be passed path to the PDF file by Evince, not the containing folder and as a result Caja will not open the folder but display an error message instead. I think this is a missing feature in Caja (I tested with version 1.24.0, newer versions may have implemented feature to open the containing folder and focus the given file as implemented in e.g. Nautilus file manager).